# Browser not asking for client certificate when CA is set in Apache

Tags: apache, ssl, certificate

UPDATED :

I updated my CA to match the CA that my client certificate was issued from and my browser now prompts me to choose a certificate (and the correct certificate is listed) but the error "ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT" persists.

---

OLD MESSAGE :

I need to make a certificate authentication with Apache.

My problem is that no certificate list pops up when the CA is set in Apache. However, not setting it brings the popup and allows me to select a certificate... but of course the authentication doesn't work and brings the following error :

> ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT

The configuration I have is the following :

**ssl.conf :**

```
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol -all +SSLv3 +TLSv1
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM

SSLCACertificateFile /etc/httpd/ca.cer
SSLCARevocationFile /etc/httpd/crl.pem
SSLCARevocationCheck chain

SSLVerifyClient optional
SSLVerifyDepth 10
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
SSLUserName SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN
```

**vhost :**

```
Include ssl.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/sub.domain.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/sub.domain.key
```

The CA is also installed on my computer along with my client certificate, ready to be used.

There's nothing in the logs, just a line mentionning a closed SSL connection.

Been searching for a while and I can't find what could be causing this.

Comment: You need to point to the chain file in the `vhost` config as well.  `SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/sub.domain.ca.crt`

Comment: @Zak: From [the documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatechainfile): *"SSLCertificateChainFile became __obsolete with version 2.4.8__, when SSLCertificateFile was extended to also load intermediate CA certificates from the server certificate file."*

Comment: Is the client certificate actually issued by any of the CA inside `/etc/httpd/ca.cer`? Because if not it will not find a matching certificate in the browser and thus not be able to choose one.

Comment: Indeed, it was a part of the problem. I updated the CA to match the CA that my client certificate was issued from. The browser now prompts me to choose a certificate and lists the good one, but the error persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright so first the **SSLVerifyDepth** parameter wasn't properly set. I was able to find this by checking Apache's **ssl_error_log** file.

And second, the log file was saying that the **CRL was not reacheable**. Even if set what I thought was the correct CRL... but **I actualy forgot the CRL of the CA that is above the clients CA** !

Thanks again for helping me with checking the CA, case closed !